Using SciPy minimize to solve the Catenary problem
I am attempting to use SciPy optimization to find the function that minimizes the potential energy of a hanging rope between 2 points, the catenary problem. The objective function is defined by

The arc length has to equal some fixed value since the rope has a fixed length.

I've tried programming this into SciPy with the following:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

y0 = 1
# Example: Define the x domain and initial guess for y
x_vals = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)  # x values from 1 to 10, 100 points
initial_y = np.ones_like(x_vals)  # Initial guess for y(x)
def objective(y_vals):
    # Number of points
    n = len(x_vals)
    
    # Reshape y_vals to be the correct shape for our problem
    y = y_vals
    
    # Calculate the finite differences for dy/dx
    dy_dx = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x_vals)
    
    # The objective function is the integral, which we approximate with the sum of the terms
    integrand = y_vals[:-1] * np.sqrt(1 + dy_dx**2)  # Use y[:-1] since dy_dx has one less point
    
    # Discretize the integral: sum the contributions from each segment
    integral = np.sum(integrand * (x_vals[1:] - x_vals[:-1]))
    
    return integral

def arc(y_vals):
    # Number of points
    n = len(x_vals)
    
    # Reshape y_vals to be the correct shape for our problem
    y = y_vals
    
    # Calculate the finite differences for dy/dx
    dy_dx = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x_vals)
    
    integrand = np.sqrt(1 + dy_dx**2)
    integral = np.sum(integrand * (x_vals[1:] - x_vals[:-1]))
    
    return integral

# Boundary conditions
def boundary_conditions(y_vals):
    return [y_vals[0] - y0, y_vals[-1]-y0, arc(y_vals)-12]  # set y0 at start and end and arc length



# Define the constraints for the optimization
constraints = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda y: boundary_conditions(y)}]

# Minimize the objective function with the constraints
result = minimize(objective, initial_y, constraints=constraints)

# Output the optimized values of y and the minimized objective value
optimized_y = result.x
print("Optimized y values:", optimized_y)
print("Minimized objective value:", result.fun)

plt.plot(optimized_y)
plt.show()

However, the result is anything but what the catenary should look like:

I suspect it may be something to do with the way I discretize the integral but I am not sure. What is the correct way of going about this problem?

For a bilinear starting configuration (two line segments), your potential energy expression evaluates to -19.9. Should the potential energy really be negative?

Can you show the source of your formulae at the top?

You can refer to this https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/7010/CM_02_CalculusVariations.html

I don't think you've specified the problem incorrectly. I think this is one of those cases where SLSQP goes crazy when it's solving a problem with constraints and either the constraints or the objective function return large numbers. (I would explain why this happens, but I've never seen a clear explanation for why this happens when using SLSQP.)
I replaced the solver with COBYQA, and it seems to make progress and avoid violating the constraint you have. Although it was progressing toward a catenary shape, it was doing so very slowly. I let it run for 10,000 iterations or so, and it produced this.
All of the solvers I tried had a very hard time solving this problem. Part of this is because of the way that the problem is specified. If the rope is 5% too long, this cannot be resolved by moving any single point. It can only be resolved by moving all of the points, which will take many iterations of the nonlinear solver.
I found two ideas that significantly help.

Solve smaller versions of the problem, and use that to solve large scale problems. When it is solving a catenary with three points, it can easily move the middle point down, and get a curve which is approximately right. Then it can double the number of points. Most movement of the rope happens with a low number of points, which saves time.
Rescale the input to the appropriate arc length. This allows the removal of the arc length constraint. (The constraint on the first and last points can also be removed, as a point which is a known constant does not need to be a variable in the problem.) This makes the solver run faster, and gives you more choices for solvers, because you no longer need a solver with constraint support.

With these two ideas, it can both solve this problem faster, and solve arbitrarily large problems.
Code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, root
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

y0 = 1
# Example: Define the x domain and initial guess for y
initial_y = np.ones(100)  # Initial guess for y(x)


def unpack(y0, y_vals):
    return np.concatenate([[y0], y_vals, [y0]])


def display_result(x_vals, y):
    plt.plot(x_vals, y, label="optimized result")
    # calculate catenary
    cat = np.cosh(np.linspace(-1, 1, len(x_vals)))
    # rescale catenary to plot
    cat -= cat.min()
    cat /= cat.max()
    cat *= (y.max() - y.min())
    cat += y.min()
    plt.plot(x_vals, cat, label="theoretical catenary")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


def potential_energy(y_vals, y0, x_vals, length):
    y_vals = rescale_y(y_vals, y0, x_vals, length)
    y_vals = unpack(y0, y_vals)
    # Number of points
    n = len(x_vals)

    # Reshape y_vals to be the correct shape for our problem
    y = y_vals

    # Calculate the finite differences for dy/dx
    dy = np.diff(y_vals)
    dx = np.diff(x_vals)
    dy_dx = dy / dx
    avg_rope_height = (y_vals[:-1] + y_vals[1:]) / 2

    # The objective function is the integral, which we approximate with the sum of the terms
    integrand = avg_rope_height * np.sqrt(1 + dy_dx**2)

    # Discretize the integral: sum the contributions from each segment
    integral = np.sum(integrand * (x_vals[1:] - x_vals[:-1]))

    return integral

def rescale_y(y_vals, y0, x_vals, length, verbose=False):
    assert not np.allclose(y_vals, y0)
    # Find scaling factor that minimizes difference from length
    result = root(
        lambda s: arc((y_vals - y0) * s + y0, y0, x_vals) - length,
        method='hybr',
        x0=[1],
    )
    y_vals = (y_vals - y0) * np.abs(result.x[0]) + y0
    assert np.abs(result.fun) < 1e-6, f"Arc is {arc(y_vals, y0, x_vals)}, but should be {length}"
    if verbose:
#             print(f"Scaling by {result.x[0]}")
        print(f"Scaling by {result.x[0]}")
    return y_vals


def arc(y_vals, y0, x_vals):
    y_vals = unpack(y0, y_vals)
    # Number of points
    n = len(x_vals)

    # Reshape y_vals to be the correct shape for our problem
    y = y_vals

    # Calculate the finite differences for dy/dx
    dy = np.diff(y_vals)
    dx = np.diff(x_vals)
    dy_dx = dy / dx

    integrand = np.sqrt(1 + dy_dx**2)
    integral = np.dot(integrand, dx)

    return integral


def recursive_secant_solver(y0, length, x_range, n):
    x_start, x_end = x_range
    x_vals = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, n)
    def display_progress(result):
        plt.plot(result)
        plt.show()

    assert n > 2
    if n == 3:
        # Solve the problem directly if it has just one free variable
        initial_guess = np.array([-1])
    else:
        # Try with half as many non-fixed points
        x_val_small, small_sol = recursive_secant_solver(y0, length, x_range, ((n - 2) // 2) + 2)
        spline = CubicSpline(x_val_small, small_sol)
        # Interpolate this onto the current points
        initial_guess = spline(x_vals)[1:-1]
    print(f"{n=}")
    result = minimize(
        potential_energy,
        initial_guess,
#         callback=display_progress,
        method='SLSQP',
        args=(y0, x_vals, length),
    )

    print(result)
    unpack_result = unpack(y0, rescale_y(result.x, y0, x_vals, length, verbose=True))
    print(f"{arc(unpack_result[1:-1], y0, x_vals)=}")
    display_result(x_vals, unpack_result)
    return x_vals, unpack_result

        
recursive_secant_solver(1, 12, (0, 10), 200)


I think your description of the problem re. constraints is correct, and starting with an estimate that does not already satisfy the constraint is essentially hopeless. But the converse shows hope: for a parabolic estimate that does satisfy the arc constraint, the solver can converge in 50-some iterations.

Linear estimate
The following works up to a resolution of 49:
import functools

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint, Bounds


def unpack(x: np.ndarray, ymid: np.ndarray, yend: float) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # y including endpoints
    np.ndarray,  # x discrete differential
    np.ndarray,  # discrete derivative
    np.ndarray,  # integrand
]:
    y = np.empty(shape=ymid.size + 2, dtype=ymid.dtype)
    y[[0, -1]] = yend
    y[1: -1] = ymid
    dx = np.diff(x)
    dy = np.diff(y)
    dy_dx = dy/dx
    integrand = np.sqrt(1 + dy_dx**2)
    return y, dx, dy_dx, integrand


def potential_energy(ymid: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray, yend: float) -> float:
    y, dx, dy_dx, integrand = unpack(x, ymid, yend)
    integrand *= y[:-1]  # Use y[:-1] since dy_dx has one less point
    return integrand.dot(dx)


def arc(ymid: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray, yend: float) -> float:
    y, dx, dy_dx, integrand = unpack(x, ymid, yend)
    return integrand.dot(dx)


def solve(
    width: float = 10.,
    resolution: int = 101,
    length: float = 12.,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    x = np.linspace(start=-0.5*width, stop=0.5*width, num=resolution)

    # The lower bound height is seen where the rope is pulled to two line segments forming
    # two right triangles; each has a hypotenuse of 0.5*length and a width of 0.5*width.
    lower_bound = -0.5*np.sqrt(length**2 - width**2)
    y0 = np.empty_like(x)
    y0[:1+resolution//2] = x[:1+resolution//2]*(2*lower_bound/width) + lower_bound
    y0[1+resolution//2:] = y0[resolution//2-1::-1]
    y0 -= lower_bound  # positive configuration
    yend = -lower_bound
    # yend = 0  # negative configuration

    # Omit the endpoints: assume 0
    y0 = y0[1: -1]

    # Sanity check
    assert np.isclose(
        length, arc(y0, x, yend), atol=1e-14, rtol=0,
    )

    result = minimize(
        fun=potential_energy, x0=y0, args=(x, yend),
        bounds=Bounds(
            lb=0, ub=yend,  # positive configuration
            # lb=lower_bound, ub=0,  # negative configuration
        ),
        constraints=NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=functools.partial(arc, x=x, yend=-lower_bound),
            lb=length, ub=length,
        ),
        options={'maxiter': 1_000},
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)

    y, x_diff, dy_dx, integrand = unpack(x, result.x, yend)
    return x, y


def main() -> None:
    x, y = solve(resolution=49)  # 101
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Any higher than that and it can't converge.
Symmetric decision variable
That could be helped by providing an analytic Jacobian (not shown), or halving the decision variables by adding an assumption of symmetry as follows:
import functools

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint, Bounds


def unpack(x: np.ndarray, ymid: np.ndarray, yend: float) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # y including endpoints
    np.ndarray,  # x discrete differential
    np.ndarray,  # discrete derivative
    np.ndarray,  # integrand
]:
    y = np.empty(shape=(ymid.size - 1)*2 + 3, dtype=ymid.dtype)

    # Symmetric assumption
    y[[0, -1]] = yend
    y[1: 1+ymid.size] = ymid
    y[ymid.size + 1: y.size-1] = ymid[-2::-1]

    dx = np.diff(x)
    dy = np.diff(y)
    dy_dx = dy/dx
    integrand = np.sqrt(1 + dy_dx**2)
    return y, dx, dy_dx, integrand


def potential_energy(ymid: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray, yend: float) -> float:
    y, dx, dy_dx, integrand = unpack(x, ymid, yend)
    integrand *= 0.5*(y[:-1] + y[1:])
    return integrand.dot(dx)


def arc(ymid: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray, yend: float) -> float:
    y, dx, dy_dx, integrand = unpack(x, ymid, yend)
    return integrand.dot(dx)


def solve(
    width: float = 10.,
    resolution: int = 101,
    length: float = 12.,
    positive: bool = True,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    x = np.linspace(start=-0.5*width, stop=0.5*width, num=resolution)

    # The lower bound height is seen where the rope is pulled to two line segments forming
    # two right triangles; each has a hypotenuse of 0.5*length and a width of 0.5*width.
    max_height = 0.5*np.sqrt(length**2 - width**2)
    y0 = x[:1+resolution//2]*(-2*max_height/width)

    if positive:
        yend = max_height
    else:
        yend = 0
        y0 -= max_height

    # Omit the endpoints: assume yend
    y0 = y0[1:]

    # Sanity check
    assert np.isclose(length, arc(y0, x, yend), atol=1e-14, rtol=0)

    result = minimize(
        fun=potential_energy, x0=y0, args=(x, yend),
        bounds=Bounds(
            lb=0 if positive else -max_height,
            ub=max_height if positive else 0,
        ),
        constraints=NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=functools.partial(arc, x=x, yend=yend),
            lb=length, ub=length+1e-3,
        ),
        options={'maxiter': 1_000},
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)

    y, x_diff, dy_dx, integrand = unpack(x, result.x, yend)
    return x, y


def main() -> None:
    x, y = solve(positive=False)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Parabolic estimate
Instead of a linear estimate, a parabolic estimate will converge more easily, but also requires the solution of a pretty tricky integral. The following converges for high resolutions, though that isn't particularly necessary given the curve smoothness.
import functools

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint, Bounds, root_scalar


def unpack(x: np.ndarray, ymid: np.ndarray, yend: float) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # y including endpoints
    np.ndarray,  # x discrete differential
    np.ndarray,  # discrete derivative
    np.ndarray,  # integrand
]:
    y = np.empty(shape=2*ymid.size + 1, dtype=ymid.dtype)

    # Symmetric assumption
    y[[0, -1]] = yend
    y[1: 1+ymid.size] = ymid
    y[ymid.size + 1: y.size-1] = ymid[-2::-1]

    dx = np.diff(x)
    dy = np.diff(y)
    dy_dx = dy/dx
    integrand = np.sqrt(1 + dy_dx**2)
    return y, dx, dy_dx, integrand


def potential_energy(ymid: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray, yend: float) -> float:
    y, dx, dy_dx, integrand = unpack(x, ymid, yend)
    integrand *= 0.5*(y[:-1] + y[1:])
    return integrand.dot(dx)


def arc(ymid: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray, yend: float) -> float:
    y, dx, dy_dx, integrand = unpack(x, ymid, yend)
    return integrand.dot(dx)


def estimate(width: float, length: float, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # Linear estimate, can have trouble converging
    # y0 = x[:1+resolution//2]*(-2*max_height/width)

    # Parabolic estimate:
    # d/dx ax2 + b = 2ax
    # length == int_{-0.5w}^{0.5w} sqrt(1 + (2ax)2)dx
    def root_error(a: float) -> float:
        x = 0.5*width
        indefinite = 0.5*x*np.sqrt(4*a*a*x*x + 1) + 0.25/a*np.asinh(2*a*x)
        return indefinite - 0.5*length

    result = root_scalar(f=root_error, x0=0.5)
    if not result.converged:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    return result.root*x**2


def solve(
    width: float = 10.,
    resolution: int = 101,
    length: float = 12.,
    positive: bool = False,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    x = np.linspace(start=-0.5*width, stop=0.5*width, num=resolution)

    # The lower bound height is seen where the rope is pulled to two line segments forming
    # two right triangles; each has a hypotenuse of 0.5*length and a width of 0.5*width.
    max_height = 0.5*np.sqrt(length**2 - width**2)

    yest = estimate(width=width, length=length, x=x)
    if positive:
        yest += max_height - yest[0]
        yend = max_height
    else:
        yest -= yest[0]
        yend = 0

    # Omit the endpoints: assume y[0]==yend; assume symmetry
    y0 = yest[1: 1+resolution//2]

    # Sanity check
    arc_estimate = arc(y0, x, yend)
    assert np.isclose(length, arc_estimate, atol=1e-3, rtol=0)

    result = minimize(
        fun=potential_energy, x0=y0, args=(x, yend),
        bounds=Bounds(
            lb=0 if positive else -max_height,
            ub=max_height if positive else 0,
        ),
        constraints=NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=functools.partial(arc, x=x, yend=yend),
            lb=length, ub=length,
        ),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    print(f'Converged in {result.nit} iterations')

    y, x_diff, dy_dx, integrand = unpack(x, result.x, yend)
    return x, yest, y


def main() -> None:
    x, yest, y = solve()
    plt.plot(x, yest, label='parabolic estimate')
    plt.plot(x, y, label='catenary')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


